# Undefined variable: playlists (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel53\resources\views\pages\playlist\index.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-5.4

I try to made a crud but I found this error :

Undefined variable: playlists (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel53\resources\views\pages\playlist\index.blade.php)

create is working... but index no...

**I am using laravel 5.4**

**and this is my controller :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth,
    Response,
    Storage,
    Session,
    Redirect,
    Validator,
    Image,
    Input;
use App\Playlist;

class PlaylistsController extends Controller {

    public function index() {

          $playlists = Playlist::all();
          return View('pages.playlist.index')->withPlaylists($playlists);

    }

    public function create() {
        return view('pages.playlist.create');
    }

    public function store(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

        $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'authors' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required',
        'url' => 'required',
        'menssage' => 'required',

        ]);
        $input = $request->all();

        Playlist::create($input);


        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Video/img successfully added!');
         return view('admin');

    }
    public function show($id) {

        $playlists = Playlist::findOrFail($id);

        return view('pages.playlist.show')->withPlaylits($playlists);

    }

    public function edit($id) {

        $playlists = Playlist::findOrFail($id);

        return view('pages.playlist.edit')->withPlaylits($playlists);

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id) {

        $playlists = Playlist::findOrFail($id);

        $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'authors' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required',
        'url' => 'required',
        'menssage' => 'required',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

    $playlists ->fill($input)->save();

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Task successfully added!');

    return redirect()->back();

}


    public function destroy($id) {


      $playlists = Playlist::findOrFail($id);

    $playlists ->delete();

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Task successfully deleted!');

    return redirect()->route('playlist.index');
}

}
```

**My index :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('content')

<h1>Task List</h1>
<p class="lead">Here's a list of all your tasks. <a href="{{ route('playlist.create') }}">Add a new one?</a></p>

<hr>

   @foreach($playlists as $playlist) 

    <h3>{{ $playlist->title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ $playlist->description}}</p>
    <p>{{ $playlist->authors}}</p>
    <p>{{ $playlist->date}}</p>
    <p>{{ $playlist->url}}</p>
    <p>{{ $playlist->menssage}}</p>

    @endforeach 

    <p>
        <a href="{{ route('playlist.show', $playlist->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">View Task</a>
        <a href="{{ route('playlist.edit', $playlist->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Task</a>
    </p>
    <hr>


@stop

        @extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: when you get the error? while visiting edit playlist page or index page? because your error msg is in edit blade. anyway for your error just use with() method not withPlayList in your index method

Comment: my erro is while i visiting index page

Comment: dont use withPlaylists(...) just use with(). see your index controller code and change

Comment: and in your index blade there are lots of unnecessary codes like @section etc

Comment: like that ? return View('pages.playlist.index')->with($playlists);

Comment: yes like this and just load a plain index.blade and print data from the controller to see

Comment: I do that but the erro continue...

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
public function index() {

      $playlists = Playlist::all();
      return View('pages.playlist.index')->with(['data', $playlists]);

}
```

In your **index blade**, just do to understand, remove blade related codes.

```
<?php 
print_r($data);
?>
```

**OR** 
You can simply do

```
public function index() {

      $playlists = Playlist::all();
      return view('pages.playlist.index',['data'=>$playlists]);

}
```

and in your index blade just do `print_r($data)` and see the result and then loop through it accordingly. Remove everything from index blade because you are extending master blade there. So remove everything (HTMLs) and just write a line of code in index blade i.e. print_r($data).

Comment: i do that but the erro continue : Undefined variable: playlists (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel53\resources\views\pages\playlist\index.blade.php)

Comment: i told you remove everything from index just write a line as <?php print_r($data); ?>

Comment: and I remove in my index.blade is just write : <?php 
print_r($data);
?>

Comment: i got this : Undefined variable: data (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\pages\playlist\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should write this in your view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('content')

<h1>Task List</h1>
<p class="lead">Here's a list of all your tasks. <a href="{{ route('playlist.create') }}">Add a new one?</a></p>
<hr>
   @foreach($playlists as $playlist) 

    <h3>{{ $playlist->title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ $playlist->description}}</p>
    <p>{{ $playlist->authors}}</p>
    <p>{{ $playlist->date}}</p>
    <p>{{ $playlist->url}}</p>
    <p>{{ $playlist->menssage}}</p>

    <p>
        <a href="{{ route('playlist.show', $playlist->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">View Task</a>
        <a href="{{ route('playlist.edit', $playlist->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Task</a>
    </p>
@endforeach 
    <hr>
@stop
        @extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
    </body>
    </html>
```

And In your controller method you write this

```
public function index() {
          $playlists = Playlist::all();
          return View('pages.playlist.index', comapct('playlists'));
    }
```

THIS WILL SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM

Comment: hello, ty for try... but the erro continue : Undefined variable: playlists (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\pages\playlist\index.blade.php)